# javascript error TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I have created a MEAN stack web application by following the tutorial http://start.jcolemorrison.com/building-an-angular-and-express-app-part-2/
After adding the signup.js as below,

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
```

I am getting below error :

> ```
> router.post('/', function (req, res) {
>       ^
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
> ```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what that tutorial is trying to get you to do, but try and see if this works:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    res.json({hello: "world"});
});
```

If it doesn't, then you've probably got a syntax error somewhere that's preventing `router` from initializing.

If it does work, then my only thought is that since `Router()` is new to Express 4.X, perhaps you're not using a 4.X version of Express? You can check by doing:

```
npm list express
```

And if necessary, upgrade by doing:

```
npm install express
```

Comment: The code you provided above does work.And when i checked the express version it came out to be 3.4.0.Please inform how whould i update the express version on my application

Comment: Upgrade to a 4.X version of Express then: run `npm install express`. The latest as of writing this is 4.13.3.